# Populate data from multipe cells to multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im able to populate date from one cell in `Sheet1` to one cell in `Sheet2`. 
By using this: `=Sheet1!B2` in `Sheet2`. How can i do it for the every cell in the B Column ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select cell which has the formula `=Sheet1!B2` then hit `Ctrl+Shift+Down Arrow` (to select all cells in the column),
then hit `Ctrl+D` (to copy formula in all cells)

Comment: Thank You, What if a cell in Sheet1 is blank how can i replace the `0` with `N/A` or nothing?

Comment: then you have to use a logic operator like =if(a1=0,N/A)

Comment: Can you give an example i tried `=IF(Sheet1!B2=0,N/A)` and it did not work.

Comment: use something like this `=IF(ISERR(Sheet1!B1),"",IF(Sheet1!B1=0,"",Sheet1!B1))`

Comment: Thanks Mate!   for your help